# Stopwords in term aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter the stop words from the term aggregation, so I defined an analyzer with a custom stop word list (around 1000 words) and applied it to my index.

If I query the index to do a term aggregation I get a result where the stopwords are dominating the result.

I tested the analyzer with

http://192.168.1.37:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=custom_analyzer

And the analyzer seems to work as it should. 
But in the term aggregation the stopwords are still shown.

Did I forget something?!

Comment: Can you post your mapping? It's pretty hard to answer a question like this without seeing it. My guess is you aren't applying your analyzer correctly.

Comment: You were right. There was a } missing and so the mapping object went into the "settings : {} object.